# Como cambiar el texto de varios botones en Unity

Tags: botón, unity, unity2d

Tengo 12 botones y quiero que se llenen con números del 1 al 12.

Quiero cambiar el texto con un script para no llenarlos manualmente, tampoco quiero hacer la referencia de los 12 botones por un `GameObject (public GameObject btn1...)` y llenarlos cada uno con `btn1.GetComponent<Text>().text`

Debe existir una forma de cambiar el texto de los botones con sólo un for.

[image: Estos son los botones que tengo]

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a S.O. en español. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), además puedes hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi ganar tu primera medalla. En cuanto a tu pregunta, ¿Has intentado algo por tu cuenta? Si es así, te invito a editar tu pregunta para que le puedas agregar el código de lo que has intentado. Saludos

Comment: Puedes agruparlos todos bajo un padre en la jerarquía. Referencias este padre en tu jerarquía y entonces haces un for por sus childs. En estos childs les cojes el componente Text y le cambias el texto. Espero que te ayude mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías agrupar los botones bajo un padre y recorrerlo, algo así

```
public void cambiarNombreBotones()
{
    //Buscas el padre
    GameObject botones = GameObject.Find("Canvas/botones");

    //recorres sus hijos
    for (int i = 0; i < botones.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        //cambias el texto (le sumo uno porque i empieza de 0)
        botones.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Text>().text = (i + 1).ToString();
    }
}
```

En mi caso la jerarquía sería así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva.

Edito: Acabo de ver que la pregunta se hizo hace varios años, imagino que ya lo solucionó, igualmente lo dejo por si a alguien le sirve.